# How to dynamically assign rowspan for data to be displayed in a table?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on creating a table in my MVC 5 web app to display auto coverages. For example, say vehicle coverage. I am trying to find a way to dynamically assign a cell's rowspan value. For instance, if you look below, there is one vehicle under an auto policy that has multiple coverages. I wish to have those coverages displayed as such:

[image: Example Display]

After doing additional research online, I could not find any way to do this. I had toyed with the idea of adding in a property for each column, such as

```
public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
public int    PolicyNumberRowspan { get; set; }
```

etc...

and assigning the value via LINQ comparisons of whether that policy number or vehicle id already exists in a previous row to assign the rowspan value in the controller and use it in my view.

Is there any other, more efficient way to achieve this? Such as through jQuery or something?

Answer (score -1):

For you reference i have created a fiddle for you:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/wVqutR

You have to change you model to be something like this(as you mentioned you have one to many relationship between policy and coverages

```
public class Policy
    {
        public string PolicyNumber  {get;set;}

        public string VehicleID{get;set; }

        public string Model {get;set;}

        public string Year  {get;set;}

        public string Make {get; set;}

        public IEnumerable<string> Coverages {  get;set;}
    }
```

You Controller would be (i have loaded some sample data)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var policies = new List<Policy>()
        {new Policy()
        {PolicyNumber = "2121", VehicleID= "2213", Model = "Abc", Year = "2011", Make = "sad", Coverages  = new List<string>()
        {"dfdfs", "dfdf"}}, new SampleViewModel()
        {Policy= "42423", VehicleID= "24422", Model = "Abdwc", Year = "2012", Make = "sad", Coverages = new List<string>()
        {"asda", "dads"}}};
        return View(policies);
    }
```

And your MCV page

```
@model IEnumerable<HelloWorldMvcApp.Policy>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- CSS Includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <style type="text/css">

            .field-validation-error {
                color: #ff0000;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>Hello Stranger</h1>

            <div><b>Table Format Data Displaying in ForEach</b><br /></div>  
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">  
    <tr>  
        <th>PolicyNumber</th>  
        <th>VehicleID</th>  
        <th>Model </th>  
        <th>Year </th>  
        <th>Make </th> 
            <th>Coverage </th> 
    </tr>  
    @foreach (var d in Model)  
    {  
        <tr>  
            <td rowspan="@d.Coverages.Count()">@d.PolicyNumber</td>  
            <td rowspan="@d.Coverages.Count()">@d.VehicleID</td>  
            <td rowspan="@d.Coverages.Count()">@d.Model</td>  
            <td rowspan="@d.Coverages.Count()">@d.Year</td>  
            <td rowspan="@d.Coverages.Count()">@d.Make</td>  
@{int i = 0; }
            @foreach (var cov in d.Coverages)
                           {
                                if (i > 0)
                               {
                                   @:</tr><tr>
                               }
                                <td >@cov</td>
                                    i++;
                           }
        </tr>  
    }  
            </table>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">



        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```